# jQuery drag and drop functionality loading Ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a dropdown element, once the select item is dragged and dropped on the `div`, the respective chart is to be loaded

```
<select id="chartsList" style="height:200px">
    <option value="1">chart1</option>
    <option value="2">chart2</option>
    <option value="3">chart3</option>
    <option value="4">chart4</option>
    <option value="5">chart5</option>
    ....
</select>
```

Ex: the image shown in the link below:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/drag-and-drop-21-5-2014

(Note: need reputation 10 to upload a image, so pasted the link)

It should be compatible with **IE-8 or above, Firefox, Chrome.** 
Could you please suggest me on how it could you be done?

Comment: Could you please tell me why it was down voted so that i can make the question clear..!

Comment: I think you should explain what you have in mind and show some code as well. The first link also do not help. You could place images in the question itself instead of showing a webpage.

Comment: Okie. thanks. Let me explain my Question